# Prove the equality of circle's areas

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, circles, area

Through a random point inside the circle, we draw $4$ lines with $45$ degrees between each other. Prove, that the total area of odd pieces, equals total area of even pieces. 
[image: Here is the picture I've made.]

I suppose there is a solution using integrals, but maybe there is geometric solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the *Pizza theorem* (or, at least, a special case of the pizza theorem). There is a standard proof without words, using the following image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_theorem):

[image]